# AddEnvironmentVariables() in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, environment-variables, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

After doing a bit of research I am still having some questions about the use of AddEnvironmentVariables() in an Azure Function. What is the use of it? How does it work?

In my application I am getting the IConfiguration value using the code below.

```
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
                .AddConfiguration(configuration) // Add the original function configuration 
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

When I work locally, everything works without AddEnvironmentVariables(), I believe this is because I have the settings values in my appsettings.json file.But I do not have environment based appsettings.

When it is deployed to Azure and the appseetings.json is overridden in the release pipeline, the app works only with .AddEnvironmentVariables().

So is .AddEnvironmentVariables() just used to override the appsettings?

Answer (score 0):

> .AddEnvironmentVariables() just used to override the appsettings?

**.AddEnvironmentVariables()** is not using for overriding the **appsettings** value. It is used to Get and add the Environment variables of Function app.

```
var existingConfig = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
var rootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                 .AddConfiguration(existingConfig) // Addding custom configuration
                .SetBasePath(rootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()  //Add the Function environment variables like application settings variable.              .AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{keyvaultName}.vault.azure.net/")
                .Build();
```

In the above line of code the **ConfigurationBuilder()** can contains all types of config values.
Here,

1. **.AddConfiguration(existingConfig)** that Add the function/application custom config values into ***ConfigurationBuilder()***
2. **.AddEnvironmentVariables()** can Add the Application Environment variables like Applicaiton Settings and Connection String values into ***ConfigurationBuilder()*** .

Comment: So from the above I understand that the existing config, local.setting.json config and the environment variables will be combined into a IConfiguration object. This object will be then used whenever a config value is requested by the application.

Comment: If all the values of the local.settings.json file is configured in Azure Portal App Service as a Configuration parameter. Then there is no need for that file right? All the values in App Service Configuration tab will be treated as an environment value and this will have priority over the values in the local.settings.json?

Comment: Yes, if you deploy your app in Azure, you don't need the `local.settings.json` file. And all the values in App Service config is an environment variable. You can confirm this in a KUDU console.

Comment: One more question,after combining all the config files and creating the IConfiguration object, I had to add it back to the IServiceCollection:  builder.Services.AddSingleton(Configuration); The config values where not available without that. Is that the right approach?